# Creating or modify function variable from outer scope python

Tags: python, function, scope

I wrote this code and received an unexpected output than I thought.

```
def egg():
    print(a)

egg() # NameError: name 'a' is not defined **As excepted**

egg.a = 50

egg() # NameError: name 'a' is not defined **Not as excepted**
```

My hope was that after setting `agg.a = 50` the next time I would call `agg()` `a` variable will be defined.

Can someone please explain what am I missing?
why `a` is not added to the function scope dynamically

p.s. when I used `dir(egg)` I could see `a` was add the the function dict

Comment: To put it simply: you can't and neither you should. If you want modifiable variable make it a parameter. Or create a class with this as an attribute.

Comment: I now understand I can't, however, my question is why?

Comment: Because it breaks function encapsulation. If inner variables were modifiable from outside the function, such code would be very hard to follow and debug.

Comment: Function attributes have nothing to do with the names visible to the function body.

Comment: lol, when you do "egg.a"  "a" is in the namepspace of "egg" not in the local namespace of code execution that is generated when the function runs statements by statements

Answer (score 1):

uisng non local params

```
def main():
    def egg():
        nonlocal a
        print(a)

    #egg() # NameError: name 'a' is not defined **As excepted**

    a = 50

    egg()
main()
```

output

```
50
```

Comment: `nonlocal` and `global` variables should be used as rarely as possible.

Comment: Agree...Just don't want to chnage the structure of the OP algorithm....Thinking for alternate solution...Meanwhile posted it

Answer (score 0):

Callable class can be used to replicate this sort of behaviour without breaking the encapsulation of a function.

```
class Egg:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __call__(self):
        print(self.a)

egg = Egg(50)

egg() # 50

egg.a = 20

egg() # 20
```

Comment: Can you please explain why `a` is not added to the function scope? Does it mean its a function attribute and not an function variable?

Comment: @RaphaelGozlan `egg.a` would be a function attribute. This is specifically not the same as `a` variable seen inside that function. I haven't encountered a single good use for such an attribute.